# WPF ComboBox - is it possible to insert your own text?

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, workflow-foundation

I have a ComboBox that contains values and you can search for a value by using the *IsTextSearchEnabled* property on the ComboBox. This works as expected.

However, in case the value isn't inside the combobox, I want the user to insert their own value, but instead of creating a textbox, I wonder if the user can just insert the value into the combobox?

At the moment when I do input a value, the combobox goes red to indicate that the value they typed cannot be found (I assume)

using this XAML

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TheValues, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Text="{Binding TheValue}"
```

The Itemsource is a list that are guids.. here is the property of the itemsource

```
public List<Guid> TheValues
{
   get
   {
      return m_TheValues;
   }
   set
   {
     m_TheValues= value;
   }
}
```

Any help (even to say it cannot be done) would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: how  you  are binding your  itemsource

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: Yeah, it might be because its type guid and not type string... I try it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUID constructors  can accept a string as a parameter try  something  like  this

```
public void AddValue(string newGuid)
        {
            Guid g  =  new Guid(newGuid);
            m_TheValues.Add(g); 
        }
```